# SGE analogue of .bashrc?

Tags: sungridengine, qsub

When I submit a job with `qsub` to SGE, the job's shell will not read `.bashrc`. Is there a file analogous to `.bashrc` that will be read by the shell of all jobs started with `qsub`?

I know there is a `.sge_request` file, but it only contains default options for `qsub`, not a list of commands like `.bashrc`. What I want is to set some environment variables for my job, like `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I don't think I can do that with `.sge_request`, but if I can, that would also solve my problem.

Comment: You can call a `config` file visible from the grid inside your job script. In my work environment my home folder is visible from the grid, thus I place all the config files for my grid jobs in there.

Answer (score 2):

This is better accomplished using the `-V` option to `qsub` , which imports all environment variables set, including those in .bashrc.

Comment: The problem with this is that it imports ALL environment variables. I get some errors because of this, with `module`.

Comment: Why not just put these into the job script, prior to executing the program that does the analysis? Or, if you want to generalize it across scripts, you could `source` the a separate script containing the variables within the job script.

Comment: Another idea is to use a `prolog` script, but that would require admin access to the cluster config (I think).

Answer (score -1):

`.bashrc` can be read if you submit an interactive job, just change the header of your job script to:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```